# A problem involving a hyperplane and an affine subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Any ideas on how to solve this??

Let $E$ be a normed vector space and let $H \subset E $ be a hyperplane. Let $V \subset E$ be an affine subspace containing $H$. Prove that either $V=H$ or $V=E$.

If $E$ is an finite dimensional vector space then this is obvious. But I don't know how to go about the general case.

Comment: What's you definition of affine subspace?

Comment: By "hyperplane" do you mean a codimension-$1$ subspace?  I'm not so clear what this means in the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: I think this all relies ultimately on working out definitions, which you should post here. It would help you get on the right track.

Comment: OK, here are the definitions at the level of generality needed. A hyperplane is a set $H=\{x \in E: f(x)=\alpha\}$ for some linear functional $f$ (not necessarily continuous) and some real number $\alpha$. An affine subspace is a subset $V$ of $E$ that can be written as $V=A+a$ for some $a\in A$ and an (ordinary) vector subspace $A$ of $E$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally worked out the way to do it. Here it is for those of you interested. Thank you Davide for your attempt. Although it was wrong it inspired my proof.

**Proof:**

Suppose $\exists x \in V \setminus H$. To see that we must have $V=E$, choose $y \in E$ arbitrary. Also, write $V=U+a$.

We will have to distinguish two cases:

- $x-y \in Ker(f)$:

In this case $f(x-y)=0$. Let $y_0 \in E$ be s.t. $f(y_0) \neq 0$. Then

$x-y=\underbrace{x-y+ \alpha \frac{y_0}{f(y_0)}}_{\in H \subset V} - \underbrace{\alpha \frac{y_0}{f(y_0)}}_{\in H \subset V}$

So we can write

$x-y=u_0+a - (u_1+a) \implies y=\underbrace{x}_{\in V} + \underbrace{u_1-u_0}_{\in U} \in V $

- $x-y \notin Ker(f)$:

In this case $f(x-y) \neq 0$. Then $\exists \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ (take $\beta=\frac{\alpha-f(y)}{f(x)-f(y)}$) s.t.

$f( \beta x+(1-\beta)y)=\alpha$

i.e. $\beta x+(1-\beta)y \in H \subset V$

$\implies \beta (a+u_0) +(1-\beta)y=a+u_1$

$\implies (1-\beta)y= (1-\beta) a + u_1-\beta u_0$

$\implies y= a + \underbrace{\frac{u_1-\beta u_0}{1-\beta}}_{\in U} \in V$

Hence, we conclude that $y\in V$ and since $y$ was arbitrary this implies that $V=E$.

$\square$

Comment: Davide's proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $H=\{f=\alpha\}$ where $f$ is a linear functional and $\alpha$ a real number. If $f\equiv 0$, either $\alpha=0$, then $H=E$ and the result is clear, or $\alpha\neq 0$ and $H$ is empty, so the result can be false, for example if $V=\{0\}$ and $E$ has a dimension $\geq 2$.

So we assume $f\neq 0$. We can write $V=W+a$ where $a\in E$ and $W$ is a linear subspace of $E$. In fact, we have the inclusion $\{f=\alpha-f(a)\}\subset W\subset E$, since $H_0:=H+(-a)=\{f=\alpha-f(a)\}$. We put $\beta :=\alpha-f(a)$. If $\beta\neq 0$, and $y_0\in E$ is such that $f(y_0)\neq 0$ then $\beta \frac{y_0}{f(y_0)}\in H\subset W$ so $y_0\in W$. So for $x\in \ker f$, $x=\underbrace{x+\beta\frac{y_0}{f(y_0)}}_{\in H_0\subset W}-\underbrace{\beta\frac{y_0}{f(y_0)}}_{\in W}$. So in any case $\ker f\subset W\subset E$. 
If $\ker f=W$ we are done (we get $H=V$) and if $\ker \subsetneq W$ and $w_0\in W\setminus\ker f$ and $x \in E$, then
$$x=\underbrace{x+\frac{\beta w_0}{f(w_0)}}_{\in H_0\subset W}-\underbrace{\frac{\beta w_0}{f(w_0)}}_{\in W},$$
so $x\in W$ and $W=E$, hence $V=E$.

Comment: I follow your argument up until you claim $x+\frac{w_0}{f(w_0)}\in H_0$. Why is this true? It should be very easy to prove since you just need to show $f(x+\frac{w_0}{f(w_0)})=\alpha-f(a)$ but I don't necessarily think that is the case for a general $x \in E$.

Comment: If $x\in \ker f$ then $f\left(x+\beta\frac{y_0}{f(y_0)}\right)=f(x)+\beta=\beta$ (it's true only for $x\in\ker f$ indeed, not for a general $x$).

Comment: Yes, that part is fine. But what I mean refers to what is below. So you agree that last part is not correct?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo , in the last math line, why is it that $x + \frac{\beta w_0}{f(w_0)} \in H_0$? We have that $f \left( x + \frac{\beta w_0}{f(w_0)} \right) = f(x) + \alpha - f(a)$, so we should have $f(x) = 0$ for your claim to be true, right?

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso beucase $x \in \text{ker}f.$