# (Functional Analysis) Hahn-Banach application

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

let ***E*** be a normed linear space with subset ***H***. I need some tips to show that if the linear functional ***f*** from ***E*** is discontinuous, then ***H*** is dense in ***E*** and ***H*** is an strict subset of ***E*** (***H*** is an hyperplane and its not closed necessarily).

Sorry for my english, I am adapted to do exercises and show theorems in spanish.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is $E$? And could you clarify the definition of $H$?

Comment: Sorry for that, E is a normed space and H is an hyperplane. H can not be closed because if it is closed, the functional f is continuous.

Comment: You're not making it clear how $H$ is related to $f$.  Presumably, $H$ is the hyperplane defined by $f(x) = c$ for some $c \in \Bbb C$.  Is that so?

Comment: Yes, sorry, H = {x in E : f(x)=c, c in Reals}.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question, I had to show that if ***H*** is an hyperplane, then ***H*** is closed or ***H*** is dense in ***E***.

Here is the link:

```
TITLE = Problem involving a hyperplane and affine subspace II
AUTHOR = Davide Giraudo
URL = http://math.stackexchange.com/q/105958
```